# Remove characters from Data key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Fetch data from `API` and store in `local storage`.

```
const products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products")).filter(
    (product) => { 
      console.log(product);
      return product.file == prize
    }
  );
```

**Result in Console**
[image]

All good over here.Now,
Need to remove `public/images/` from `file` key.

Try to use this, but getting error

> Line 19:7:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw
> an expression  no-unused-expressions
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
const products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("products")).filter(
    (product) => { 
      console.log(product);
      product.file == product.file.replace("public/images/","");
      return product.name == prize
    }
  );
```

**Plateform: ReactJs**

Comment: Instead of `console.log` image, can you add the sample input and outputs. So that it'll be easy for anyone to help.

Comment: @Nithish, can you check my question again, I updated with what I was trying.

Comment: So, basically you want to replace `public/images/` with "" for a matching `name` value? or for all the objects you want to replace?

Comment: just the value of `file` key

Comment: Bro can you include a screenshot of the line numbers ?

Comment: The error ` Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions` is because of this line `product.file == product.file.replace("public/images/","");`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to replace `public/images/` for all the items in the array you can use `Array.map` instead of `Array.filter`

```js
let data = [{id:3,name:'Spring Water Bottle',file:'public/images/Spring Water Bottle.png'},{id:4,name:'Osaka Emergency Labs',file:'public/images/Osaka Emergency Labs.png'},{id:5,name:'Mobile',file:'public/images/Mobile.png'}];

const replaceData = (data) => data.map(d => ({
  ...d,
  file: d.file.replace("public/images/", "")
}))


console.log(replaceData(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If you want to replace only for the items where the provided `name` is matching with the `name` in the object then you can use below.

```js
let data = [{id:3,name:'Spring Water Bottle',file:'public/images/Spring Water Bottle.png'},{id:4,name:'Osaka Emergency Labs',file:'public/images/Osaka Emergency Labs.png'},{id:5,name:'Mobile',file:'public/images/Mobile.png'}];

const replaceData = (data, name = "") => {
  return data.map(d => ({
    ...d,
    ...(d.name === name && { file: d.file.replace("public/images/", "")})
  }))
}

console.log(replaceData(data, "Mobile"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```